# conversejs overrides is not working when I try to show icon in massages

Tags: xmpp, converse.js

I am trying to override the **renderActions** function but it is not working, I am trying to add icons in every massage, I have tried like the below code:

```
export const restrictUserOnLoadPlugin = () => {
  window.converse.plugins.add('restrict-user', {
    overrides: {
      renderActions: function () {
        console.log('in');
        const kick = {
          i18n_text: 'kick',
          handler: (e: any) => console.log(e),
          button_class: 'chat-msg__action-edit',
          icon_class: 'fa fa-pencil-alt',
          name: 'kick',
        };
        return `<converse-dropdown class="chat-msg__actions" .items=${kick}></converse-dropdown>`;
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Using overrides is discouraged and should be avoided when possible. They only work with classes or objects that have been set as attributes on the `_converse` object, which is not the case for web components, which is what you're trying to override here. So it won't work.

Instead you should use the `getMessageActionButtons` hook to add or update buttons.
https://conversejs.org/docs/html/api/-_converse.html#event:getMessageActionButtons

Here is documentation which describes how hooks work:
https://github.com/conversejs/converse.js/blob/3b124cfdceb684ccbe3d20f7ea5cde20a1189f0b/docs/source/plugin_development.rst#hooks

So your code would be something like this:

```
    api.listen.on('getMessageActionButtons', (chatbox, buttons) => {
        buttons.forEach((button) => {
            button.icon_class = "my-icon-class";
        });
        return buttons;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you I think this hook will work with version 9 and I am using 7.0.5, so I did it by dom manipulation.

Comment: I have created another question related to converse js, if you can suggest me your answer that would be appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73038783/is-there-any-way-to-send-a-message-automatically-in-converse-js